# Tensorboard not listing any event

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Running Tensorflow and Tensorboard on docker here.

I was trying to write the simplest code to just demonstrate how tensorboard may work:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant(5.0)
  b = tf.constant(6.0)
  c = a * b

  # Enter data into summary.
  c_summary = tf.scalar_summary("c", c)
  merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("log/test_logs", session.graph_def)

  result = session.run([merged])
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  writer.add_summary(result[0], 0)
```

I then ran `tensorboard --logdir={absolute path to log/test_logs}` but no event was listed there. Is there anything I should have written differently in the code maybe?

Note that `log/test_logs` does contain files like `events.out.tfevents.1459102927.0a8840dee548`.

Comment: what if you give "log" instead of "log/test_logs" as --logdir argument

Comment: Still nothing, it shows empty event.

Comment: Is the `graph` showing correctly?

Comment: If your graph is showing correctly, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37684739/656912) may be related.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is your case.

`SummaryWriter` by default will store summaries in its buffer, it will flush every period of time(I guess 120 seconds? Not sure).

So maybe you just did not wait until your the flush happens. Try to manually flush `SummaryWriter` or just `close()` it at the end of your program.