# TensorBoard shows no histograms or events

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Running TensorBoard r0.9 results in graph visualizations as expected but all events and histograms that successfully displayed in r0.8 are not.

Has r0.9 introduced a change to the command line that should be used to launch TensorBoard, or to the code needed to generate events and histograms for TensorBoard to display?

Note that neither new summaries and histograms written with recent runs using r0.9 TensorFlow, nor existing ones written (and displayed) in the past, are displayed. Graphs generated with both releases display as expected.

Comment: This sounds like a bug! Could you post this on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues with some reproduction steps?

Comment: @PeteWarden: This is a cross post of [#2708](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2708).

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Safari? I had the same problem, then I found this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2708

I just changed to Chrome and the events are showing.